# How can I expose the Math object properties to the window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, properties, iteration

I want to expose the `Math` properties to the `window` in JavaScript. This way, I'd be able to do things like `pow(n, n)` instead of `Math.pow(n, n)`.

I've tried using the following methods, but neither work.

```js
for (var obj in Math) window[obj.name] = obj;
```

Returns undefined

```js
for (var obj of Math) window[obj.name] = obj;
```

Throws error: `Math object is not iterable.`

Comment: _"I'd be able to do things like pow(n, n) instead of Math.pow(n, n)"_: why?

Comment: @Andy I guess it's just a personal preference. The code won't be seen by anybody but me so I don't worry about other people being confused by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab Math's property names, then assign them to `window`.

```js
const arr = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);
arr.forEach(el => window[el] = Math[el]);
console.log(pow(7,2))
```